# How do obtain additional process information in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In powershell, if I do 'get-process', I get

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\Hello\Desktop> get-process -name excel

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    312      11    13124      25196   121    58.50  13180 EXCEL
```

However, using ps from mkstools I can get these:

```
C:\\workarea\>ps | grep -i excel
13964 12:17 "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office10\excel.exe"  
16144 31:12 "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office10\excel.exe"  
13180  0:58 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\excel.exe" /automation -Embedding
12624  0:56 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\excel.exe" /automation -Embedding
12388  0:00 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\excel.exe" /automation -Embedding
```

I only want to kill those excel automation objects and `ps` can help me distinguish the excel runtimes I created via Start menu and those via COM calls.

How can I show the `/automation -Embedding` bit in the powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Process` doesn't return the command line information, but the WMI class Win32_Process does. To use WMI classes, use the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet which has the alias `gwmi`.

To kill all excel automation objects, you could use:

```
gwmi Win32_Process -filter "Name='Excel.exe'"| 
    where { $_.CommandLine -match '/automation -Embedding' }|
    foreach { $_.Terminate() }
```